# Easy proof of falsehood of $\pi(n) \leq C \cdot \text{ln}(n)$ for the prime counting function $\pi$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-gaps

Let $\pi(n)$ be the number of primes in the range $1,\dotsc,n$.

The following statement is true: There is no $C>0$ such that $\pi(n) \leq C \cdot \text{ln}(n)$ for all $n\geq 1$.

It follows immediately from the prime number theorem which is a much stronger result.

Still, since the above statement is much weaker than the PNT, I was wondering if it has a simple proof.

> Is there a proof of the above theorem which is simpler than the known proofs of the prime number theorem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are all kinds of rougher estimates, for example  you can use Chebyshev's estimate to show that $\pi (x) > c x/ \log (x) $ for a positive c and large enough x.

Comment: Thank you. I looked for the proof. It is indeed much easier than PNT's. Nevertheless, it is still much stronger than what I need, so maybe there are even simpler proofs of what I need

Comment: Another way is $-\log (s-1) \sim \log \zeta(s) \sim \sum_p p^{-s} = s \int_1^\infty \pi(x) x^{-s-1}dx$

Comment: @reuns: Can you elaborate?

Comment: $\pi(x) = O(\ln x)$ means the integral converges for $\Re(s) > 0$ contradicting its singularity at $s=1$